# BroadcastReceiver inner class not trigger

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a Watch Dog function using an inner class broadcast receiver. On the parent class I registered the broadcast receiver inside the constructor, but the onReceive class is never trigger.

How can I solve this issue ? Thank you.

WatchDog class:

```
public class WatchDog {
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private static final String RECEIVER_WATCHDOG = "com.example.liviu.test_broadcastreceiver.receiver";
private final static String ACTION_WATCHDOG = "com.example.liviu.test_broadcastreceiver.action.watchdog";
private final static int ID_WATCHDOG = 40856342;
private final static int mTimeout = 1000;

public WatchDog (Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, ":::::::::::: Watchdog CONSTRUCTOR");
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(RECEIVER_WATCHDOG);
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new WatchDogReceiver();
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    setWatchdogTimer(context, true, mTimeout);
}

final class WatchDogReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, ":::::::::::: Watchdog received - ");
        setWatchdogTimer(context, true, mTimeout);
    }
}

public void setWatchdogTimer(Context context, boolean set, int timeout) {
    Log.d(TAG, ":::::::::::: Watchdog START");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WatchDogReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_WATCHDOG);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID_WATCHDOG, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (set) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout, alarmIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

}

and MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>> Activity START");
    new WatchDog(getApplicationContext());
}
```

}

Logcat is showing only:

```
05-02 18:11:10.197 20415-20415/com.example.liviu.test_broadcastreceiver D/MainActivity: >>>>>>>>>>>> Activity START
05-02 18:11:10.197 20415-20415/com.example.liviu.test_broadcastreceiver D/WatchDog: :::::::::::: Watchdog CONSTRUCTOR
```

Comment: Your receiver is not public, and I would double check to ensure that it is in your manifest.

Comment: How exactly are you sending a broadcast to the receiver?  From the code you currently have in the question, it doesn't look like you send anything to the receiver, so those logs are the expected result as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you trying to set a repeating alarm?

Comment: @DanielNugent - you are right, I forgot to call setWatchdogTimer(context, true, mTimeout); at the end of the constructor. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkPazon - yes, is a repeating alarm that is checking if a service is alive and start again if not. Of course the trigger time is not 1s, it will be few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want dynamic register/unregister then register on onResume and unregister on  onPause().  If you want to do it statically, register it on manifest and make your nested class static so manifest can instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the receiver registered in the manifest? It will need to be.

e.g.

```
<receiver
android:name=".receivers.WatchDog$WatchDogReceiver"/>
```

Comment: That is not true. If you're using `registerReceiver()` to register the receiver at runtime, there is no need to do anything in the manifest.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. After I add: <receiver android:name=".WatchDog$WatchDogReceiver"/> in the manifest is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setWatchdogTimer()` at least once to be able to set an alarm.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>> Activity START");
    WatchDog watchDog = new WatchDog(getApplicationContext());
    watchdog.setWatchdogTimer(this, true, 1000);
}
```

Also consider using `LocalBroadcastReceiver` if the BroadcastReceiver will be local to your app.

Comment: If I call setWatchdogTimer in this way: watchDog.setWatchdogTimer(this, true, 1000); I received the error posted at the end of this message 
But if I change the WatchDogReceiver class and setWatchdogTimer(...) method to static, also your solution works:

WatchDog.setWatchdogTimer(this, true, 1000);

Thank you

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.liviu.test_broadcastreceiver.WatchDog$WatchDogReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.liviu.test_broadcastreceiver.WatchDog$WatchDogReceiver; no empty constructor